# Intermittent error with Azure and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, azure

I have a site on Azure and all during development and now production I've occasionally seen a page of garbage characters come back in IE9. It happens on the emulator and live servers. I assume its a problem in IIS. When this happens locally I just restart the app, but on the production server I have to cycle the server or re-publish the app.  When it is in this state all attempts to load the page in IE either result in garbage characters or it asks to save the return or open it in some other program (3.5k). My page is 9.6k so I know its not that. Oddly when it is in this state, it all still works fin from firefox or chrome.

Here is a snippet of what I see:
ìZmsÛÆñŸ™|‡Ú1ÀJH)Û’¨üeÉùWSÅÑÈrÜ

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: More alarming now that my app has gone live, I am getting infrequent reports of people seeing this error. One on Safari, one on IE. I don't see any commonality, but one time when I had the person on the phone (and reproducing the error 100% of the time) I re-deployed the instances and the error stopped. This has to be something with IIS and/or Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an app/code issue, or maybe the browser, but not something with Windows Azure.

Comment: Possibly not Azure - I haven't run it outside the emulator or production environment.  My pages are simple .htm files and the web.config is pretty straight forward. Perhaps now that I write this, it could be a side effect of FluorineFx running on the same instance.